# ATMega8U2 and DFU mode

Tags: arduino, usb, atmega, fuse-bits

I made simple board with ATMega8U2 microcontroller for my USB experimenting (I'd like to make MIDI, HID, ... devices). I took inspiration in Arduino Uno. If you look on schematic below, you can see it is almost the same as Uno.

I programmed 8U2 with firmware from Arduino project — [UNO-dfu_and_usbserial_combined.hex](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/firmwares). Now, if I connect board to USB, I get serial port and it works just like Arduino, so this is perfectly OK.

My problem is: how can I put 8U2 into DFU mode, so I can change firmware without external programmer? If you look on picture, I connected HWB (pin PD7) to ground, so it should be simple — just pressing reset button. Unfortunately, it isn't working.

Am I missing something? Can be a problem in wrong fuse bites?

**Edit:** My fuses are lfuse=0xff hfuse=0xd9 efuse=0xf4

**Edit2:**

I checked fuses on chip

```
$ avrdude -p at90usb82 -P /dev/tty.usbmodem411 \
> -F -c arduino \
> -U lfuse:r:low:h \
> -U hfuse:r:high:h
$ cat high low
0x00
0x00
```

For programing, I'm using Arduino Uno as ISP and this commant (on Mac):

```
$ avrdude -p at90usb82 -F -P /dev/tty.usbmodem411 \
> -c arduino \
> -U flash:w:UNO-dfu_and_usbserial_combined.hex \
> -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m \
> -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m \
> -U efuse:w:0xF4:m \
> -U lock:w:0x0F:m
.......
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
  0xff != 0x00
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

So I suppose, avrdude did not programed fuses and they are still blank. Is it possible? Because board is working corrently, except DFU mode after reset.

[image: Schematic ATMega8U2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the HWBE bit (HardWare Boot Enable) set in your fuses?

Comment: HWBE bit is cleared (=zero). My fuses are: lfuse=0xff hfuse=0xd9 efuse=0xf4

Comment: Ok, so problem was in fuses. I do not know why, but `hfuse` wasn't set.

Comment: So what the fuses should be after setting the HWBE bit ?